# Nginx redirecting every POST to homepage

Tags: nginx, flask

I have a flask app running with Gunicorn behind a nginx proxy server. The flask app serves different content for "/" and "/submit," but when I send a postman request to "myapp.net/submit," the "/" endpoint's content is returned. When accessing "/submit" in a web browser, I get a 404 not found response. I feel this must be nginx doing this, but can't figure out why.

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
upstream pokemonmapper_server {
    server unix:/home/pi/web/run/gunicorn_pokemon.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name pokemonmapper.net www.pokemonmapper.net;

        client_max_body_size 4G;

        access_log /home/pi/web/logs/nginx-access.log;
        error_log /home/pi/web/logs/nginx-error.log;

        location /static/ {
                alias /home/pi/web/pokemapper-server/static/;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_pass http://pokemonmapper_server;
        }
}
```

I've looked through the various tutorials and they are all similar to this nginx.conf file, is there something obvious that I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried disabling nginx and running your app at 0.0.0.0 for test?

Comment: Yes, running gunicorn on 0.0.0.0 yields the correct response for the /submit endpoint.